# SliderObject.onValueChanged listener taking long as a parameter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, listener

I need the user to pass a `long` via a slider. However I can't add *a function that takes `long` as a parameter* as a listener to the slider. See [this](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Slider.html) under "Events".

The float causes a precision loss issue. How can I work around this?

The script I'm currently using is similar to this. The listener function takes a `float`:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Events;

public class SliderMessageBox : MonoBehaviour
{
  public Slider SliderObject;
  public Text SliderFeedback;

  public void Function(long MaximumValue)
  {
    SliderObject.minValue = 1000;
    SliderObject.maxValue = MaximumValue;
    SliderObject.onValueChanged.AddListener(SetFeedback);
    SetFeedback(SliderObject.value);
  }

  void SetFeedback(float value)
  {
    SliderFeedback.text = value.ToString("#");
  }
}
```

Comment: It should be `long MaximumValue` not `Long MaximumValue`...

Comment: So your problem is solved?

Comment: no no I need to replace `void SetFeedback(float value)` with something like `void SetFeedback(long value)` but that's not possible. @Programmer

Comment: Ok. I get it. Where do you get the `long` value you will pass to the `SetFeedback` function?

Comment: The function is added as a listener to the slider. This slider just gives it the value at runtime. I don't exactly know how it works "as code". @Programmer

Comment: I have another question, what is calling the `Function` function and when is that called?

Comment: I call it "manually" from another script. It's called when the user clicks one of certain buttons. So I guess I can say that the original function calling this function is a `void OnMouseDown()` function in another script. @Programmer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't call `SliderObject.onValueChanged.AddListener(SetFeedback);` each time a `Button` is clicked. You should call that function **once**, to register to a slider value change event. That line of code should be moved to the `Start()` function.

As for passing `long` to the `SetFeedback` function when slider value changes, that is **possible** but totally useless. The reason for this is because the `Slider` component is designed to work with with floats in its `minValue`, `maxValue` and `value` properties. Assigning `long` to these properties will not solve your precision problem.

If you still want to do that, here is a way to do it with `delegate` and casting:

```
public Slider SliderObject;
public Text SliderFeedback;

void Start()
{
    SliderObject.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate { SetFeedback((long)SliderObject.value); });
}

public void Function(long MaximumValue)
{
    SliderObject.minValue = 1000;
    SliderObject.maxValue = MaximumValue;
    SetFeedback((long)SliderObject.value);
}

void SetFeedback(long value)
{
    SliderFeedback.text = value.ToString();
}
```

That should compile but the correct way to fix your problem is to implement your own custom `Slider` component and make its `minValue`, `maxValue` and `value` properties to be `long`. You can implement this with the help of `Image` component.

Also, Unity UI is open source. You can also get the source code from [here](https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/ui/), duplicate the Slider script, name it `BigSlider` then change all `float` variables to `long`.

Comment: uuuuh no so I have to modify the slider from the inside. that's sounds like a lot of work! X') ...about calling the function once, it's because in a part of the project I made a message box system that instantiates a message box when the button is pressed. I call this function right after instantiation. ...I know it's a bad way for making message boxes but it's because that was before I knew a better way. I have to modify lots of code if I want to make things cleaner so for now it's just fine and working so I'm keeping it. ...I guess it'd be the same thing for the float parameter unfortunately

Comment: Ok. Now I understand why you are doing that.As for modifying the slider, it's not hard.   Get the source code, replace floats with long then re-compile it. That's it.  **"I guess it'd be the same thing for the float parameter unfortunately"** Yup it looks like, unless the modification is done! The link I provided has build instructions there which is really easy.