# Unity Slider does not return a value in the Script

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine

When I have a UI Slider in Unity and connect a Script function to this element.

As you can see here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdMuG.jpg

I have a Gameobject called "SettingsMenu" with a script attached "SettingsController".

In this Script I have a function

```
 public void GetPlanetCount(float sliderVal)
    {
        planetObjectsCount = Mathf.RoundToInt(sliderVal);
    }
```

As you can see on the picture I have connected the method to the slider. But this method is never called.

Does someone know what is missing there?
I do not know much about the UI system at the moment

Answer (score 2):

Its not getting called because you plugged in the script to the `Object` slot.

From your screenshot where it says "*SettingsMenu (SettingsController)*", you are suppose to plugin the *SettingsMenu* GameObject there **not** the *SettingsController* script.

Then on the right, you select the *SettingsController* script and the function.

*Here is an image steps for that*:

[image]

You can also do this from script. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39313885/3785314).

Comment: What did you use to generate that animation?

Comment: **LICEcap**. Records gif directly. Simply select screen region to record.

Comment: You are welcome! Don't forget to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) if your problem is solved. You have not done this to any of your questions.

Comment: Don't forget to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) if your problem is solved. You have not done this to any of your questions.